# Is it possible to clean up the message produced by ${arg?word} failures

Tags: bash, shell, sh

When bash is interpreting a script and encounters

```
${arg?error message}
```

when arg is unset, the script terminates after printing the error message.  Unfortunately, bash prepends "$0: line $LINENO: arg:" to the error message.  Is it possible to suppress the additional information?  I would like the error message to be exactly "error message".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have to avoid the `${PARAMETER?WORD}` construct and do it manually. For example, something like

```
if [ -z "${arg+set}" ]; then
    printf 'error message\n' >&2
    exit 2
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that if you're wanting to do this, you may not be accomplishing your ultimate purpose in the way that is most natural in Bash. Something like this should be better:

```
if [ -z $arg ]; then
    echo error message >&2;
else
    $arg
fi
```

Answering the question more directly, though:

```
(${arg?error message}) |& sed "s/.*: .*: //"
```

Explanation: The `|&` connects the standard error of the block of code in the parentheses (which are necessary for this to work, by the way) into `sed` (stream editor), which strips off the part of the message you don't want with a regular expression.

Comment: |& is a syntax error in bash.  I believe that is a csh construct.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Actually, sir, I tested it in Bash and it worked just fine.

Comment: @WilliamPursell If `|&` doesn't work for you for some reason, `2>&1 |` should do the trick as well; it's just not quite as concise.